# Force node to be directly beneath another node

Tags: graph, graphviz, dot

I have a graph that's laid out from left-to-right.  There are some elements of this graph, however, that I want to have positioned relative to another node.  For example, if I have this graph:

```
digraph "Test" {
    rankdir = "LR"
    A -> B
    B -> C
    D -> B
    note -> B

    note [ shape="house" ]
};
```

It renders like this:

[image: Normal DOT layout]

However, I'd like the "note" node to always be positioned directly underneath the node to which it's pointing, like this (manually created) graph:

[image: Desired DOT layout]

I've tried experimenting with a subgraph with a different `rankdir` and fiddling with `rank` and `constraint` attributes, but have been unsuccessful in getting this to work, as I've only been playing around with DOT for a couple of days.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can enumerate the nodes before defining the edges, and then *constrain* node `B` to the same rank as node `note` by putting them in a *subgraph*:

```
digraph "Test" {
    rankdir = "LR"
    A;D;
    {rank=same; note; B;}
    C;

    A -> B
    B -> C
    D -> B
    B -> note [dir=back]

    note [ shape="house" ]
};
```

Please note that in order to have node `note` below node `B`, I had to reverse the edge direction and add `dir=back` to have the arrow drawn correctly.

[image: graphviz output]

Comment: +1 this is proving to be the most consistent in its results and gives me something to go on.  Thanks! :)

Comment: ^^^ Agreed!  Being able to directly control ranks was definitely news to me, thank you for spelling it out so clearly!!!

Comment: This causes a lost edge in my graph

Answer (score 3):

A general technique for moving nodes around is to create invisible edges.  In your case, you could create an edge from `A` to `note`, mark it invisible, and then mark the edge from `note` to `B` as non-constraining:

```
A -> note [style="invis"];
note -> B [constraint=false];
```

Comment: +1 This isn't working very consistently in my case, but it's an interesting technique. Thanks!